# mysqldump throwing error in perl script , but running fine outside script

Tags: mysql

I have a script where i take backups through perl script , which is throwing error as mentioned below

> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) when trying to connect

I have the root user with with localhost mentioned as % , as per documentation all the host are allowed .

And interesting point is the mysqldump command is running fine outside script ,i.e in shell prompt

Any ideas ????

Comment: Can you provide perl command you are using to create mysqldump please?

Comment: `foreach my $database (@databases){
        chomp($database);
        `mysqldump -u backup -pbackup $database > $backup_folder/$date_folder/$database.sql`;
                }
`tar -cvzf $date_folder.tar.gz $date_folder`;
`rm -rf $date_folder`;`
it worked fine till yesterday , but as i traced out its not the script problem , its mysql thing related to users and privileges as far as i understood

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to check if `root` has permissions to connect from localhost

```
SELECT user,host 
FROM mysql.user
WHERE user = 'root'
```

If you do not have an entry with `localhost` in the `host` column, then `root` is **NOT** allowed to connect from `localhost`. You should allow `root` to connect from `locolhost` by issuing a `GRANT`.

Comment: I have added a root user with localhost , but still the problem persists , created another user and granted privileges , as of now its working but want to know what's the real problem is